# laravel5 redirecting after registration doesn't work

Tags: laravel-5

i am using laravel 5 to do a recipe app.i want to be redirected to my    recipe listing page after registration.

I have the following

**route.php**

```
Route::resource('recipe', 'RecipesController');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

In AuthController.php i added this

```
protected $redirectTo = '/recipe';
```

recipe is a folder containing index,edit and create .blade.php files but every time i press the register button it redirects to home and shows me a bunch of errors

Comment: One tip, make sure to post any related errors in your post, this makes it easier to find out exactly what goes wrong in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`Route::resource('recipe', 'RecipesController');` Means that a [RESTful resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) will be used when a url with 'recipe' as a prefix will be encountered.

In your case, a GET request to `/recipe` would be handled by the function `index()` in your RecipesController.

---

If your RecipesController is not a resource controller, but a "regular" one, you'll want this:

```
Route::get('/recipes', 'RecipeController@showRecipes');
```

In this case you can substitute `showRecipes` with the name of the function you use to handle the request.

Another option (when your controller is not a resource controller) is to register the controller in routes.php like this:

```
Route::controllers([
    ...,
    'recipes' => 'RecipeController',
]);
```

This will make routes automatically assume which function names you use for your routes. Like, a GET request to '/recipes' would be `function getRecipes()` whereas a POST request to the same URL would be handled by `function postRecipes()`.

Comment: For the last mentioned solution, also check out the documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#implicit-controllers

Comment: I am using the restful approach and i want it to go to http://localhost:8080/recipe/ but it always redirects to http://localhost:8080/home and shows me "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:"

Comment: Are you certain that `/recipes` works? Also, have you tried making `redirectTo` a public property? (I'm not sure whether the `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait can read your protected variable, so it's a guess on my side).